# Java Applet - Possible to insert data into a MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, applet, japplet

So I have a JApplet that was originally a stand alone program. In order to extend it I've converted it into a JApplet.

What I now want to do is everytime data is submitted to the JApplet I would like the contents inserted into a MySQL database. Now, I have no idea how to do this or even if it can be done but I'd like to give it a go!

The idea is that I'll have a separate PHP page to display data inserted into the JApplet form.

Any solutions, comments or pointers would be very handy as I haven't done this before!

Comment: *"So I have a JApplet that was originally a stand alone program. In order to extend it.."*  ..deploy the app. from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It will be easier for you, and a better experience for the user.  I agree with @favoretti that generally neither an applet nor desktop app. should have direct access to the DB.  Make them connect via a servlet or similar.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand of the whole concept, Applets are client-side executables. So basically if your applet will establish communication with the server (preferably not a direct MySQL connection, but via REST API or other sort of client-server comms) you can insert the data. Otherwise, to address your MySQL database directly from your Java code - you can convert your program to be a servlet and run it in an application container on the server.

Comment: This is very useful to know, thanks! Why is it preferable not to have the applet make a direct MySQL connection (unless it's a servlet)?

Comment: Well, if it's a local intranet application you can opt for that as well, if it's an application intended to have MySQL server on internet and client apps anywhere - it will mean you will have to open access to MySQL (although pass-protected) to the whole world, and there are some quite nasty bugs in MySQL auth every now and then. Plus, MySQL runs on a port that can be blocked by various ISPs. So choice is up to you of course and depends on the solution that you're trying to build and its goals.